# How to compute the FGLS estimator for simulated data in Matlab (or any other language really)?

Tags: matlab, estimators, generalized-least-squares

first time posting here so please let me know if I can improve my question.

As an exercise, I have to simulate 1000 iterations of a sample of 500 observations from a linear model:
$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i $$

$$\varepsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma_i^2) ,\ \  \sigma_i^2 = a + b\,x_i^2 $$

Notice the errors are independent, so covariance is zero.

Then, i have to compute the OLS and fGLS estimator (assuming that the true variance structure $\hat{\varepsilon_i}^2 = a + b \, x_i^2$ is known). I am supposed to compute the estimators myself, without using ad-hoc packages or functions.

My problem is that when I try to create the FGLS estimator I get absurd results and I don't know where I'm making a mistake.
Here the steps I took:

1. Get residuals $e$ from OLS and square them
2. estimate $a$ and $b$ in $e_i^2 = a + b \, x_i^2$ with OLS
3. Compute the fitted values of the variance as $\hat{\sigma_i}^2 = \hat{a} + \hat{b}\,x_i^2$ and transform it into a diagonal matrix
4. Use the inverse of this error variance estimate as the weight to compute the FGLS estimators for $\beta$ and its variance.

The code I made:

```
N = 500;   % n. of observations
S = 1000;   % n. of simulations
beta = [1; 0.5];   %true value of parameters
a = 0.2;   % true intercept of variance model
b = 0.6;   % true slope of variance model
betaHatOLSstore = zeros(2,S);   sigma2HatOLSstore = zeros(2,S);   % Here I store the OLS results across iterations
betaHatfGLSstore = zeros(2,S);   sigma2HatfGLSstore = zeros(2,S);   % Same with FGLS

for i=1:S
    % Create the Data Generating process
    x = randn(N,1);   % random regressors vector
    X = [ones(N,1),x];   % construction of the regressors matrix by adding a column of ones
    sigma2 = diag(a + b * x.^2);   % create the true error variance
    eps = normrnd(0,diag(sigma2));   % N(0, sigma^2) errors 
    Y = X*beta + eps;   % generate true Ys by linear model 

    % OLS estimation
    betaHat_ols = (X'*X)\(X'*Y);   % beta estimate
    yHat_ols = X*betaHat_ols;   % fitted values
    e_ols = Y - yHat_ols;   % residuals
    RSS_ols = e_ols'*e_ols;   % Residual Sum of Squares
    sigma2Hat_ols = RSS_ols/(N-1);   % sigma2 estimate
    varBetaHat_ols = sigma2Hat_ols * diag(inv(X'*X));   % variance of beta estimate
    betaHatOLSstore(:,i) = betaHat_ols;   % Store betaHat_ols value across simulations
    sigma2HatOLSstore(:,i) = varBetaHat_ols;   % Store varBetaHat_ols across simulations

    % I also store the standardised estimates of beta to compare the estimation errors
    std_OLS_store(1,i) = (betaHat_ols(2) - beta(2))/sqrt(sigma2HatOLSstore(2,i));


    % Feasible GLS estimation
    X_2 = (X.^2);   % square the regressors
    e_2 = e_ols.^2;   % take the residuals from OLS and square them
    gammaHat = (X_2' * X_2)\(X_2' * (e_2));   % a and b estimates through OLS
    sigma2Hat_fgls = (diag(X_2 * gammaHat));   % estimate sigma2 with the fitted values
    betaHat_fgls = (X' * (sigma2Hat_fgls \ X)) \ (X' * (sigma2Hat_fgls \ Y));   % beta estimate
    varBetaHat_fgls = diag(X'*(sigma2Hat_fgls\X));   %variance of beta FGLS estimate
    betaHatfGLSstore(:,i) = betaHat_fgls;   % Again, I store all values of betaHat
    sigma2HatfGLSstore(:,i) = varBetaHat_fgls;   % Store variance estimates
    std_fGLS_store(1,i) = (betaHat_fgls(2) - beta(2))/sqrt(sigma2HatfGLSstore(2,i));   % Store standardised betaHats
```

When I run, I get absurd values for basically all parameters for the FLGS estimation (and obviously silly graphs too), while the OLS works fine.

Can you please help me spot what I'm doing wrong? I scripted this in matlab but of course the question is general. The code is fairly simple, and for who is not familiar with matlab the only thing to notice is what the backslash and forward-slash mean: $A\backslash b = inv(A) * b$ and $b/A = b * inv(A)$. All the rest I guess is straightforward.

I'm really stuck here, if any other info is needed please let me know and thanks a lot!